# Accessing an API endpoint on the same website using D3.JS

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am putting together a D3.JS visualization, as a part of which I have created a MongoDB database and exposed it via an API endpoint on my webservice. I am using Python `Flask` to do this.

I've validated that the data emitted is in valid JSON format and I've made sure to set the MIME type to `application/json`. However, while in visiting the URL in question everything is fine, when I try to call into that URL using `d3.json`:

```
d3.json("http://127.0.0.1:5000/citibike-api/bike-inbounds/id/72", function (data, error) {
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Console yells at me:

```
uncaught exception: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Are there other things that I need to do to make this request work?

Do I need something with `JSONP` to do this?

Comment: Stringify the exception so you can understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap `data` with `error`. Instead of:

```
d3.json("http://127.0.0.1:5000/citibike-api/bike-inbounds/id/72", function (data, error) {
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(data);
});
```

It should be:

```
d3.json("http://127.0.0.1:5000/citibike-api/bike-inbounds/id/72", function (error, data) {
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(data);
});
```

**Explanation**

According to the API, in `d3.json`...

> ...the callback is invoked with two arguments: the error, if any, and the parsed JSON

The argument `error` is optional. You can just write:

```
function (data){
```

But, if you use the argument `error`, the sequence has to be:

```
function (error, data){
```

Comment: Ugh. Such a simple error!

What's the logic behind this argument order? I've never seen errors first before.

Comment: To answer my own comment: I believe now that this is done so that `error` is always a predictably locate-able argument of the function no matter how many additional arguments the function, as implemented, accepts. Languages which allow keyword declarations avoid this gotcha entirely.